# Mysql, group by and subquery in one row

Tags: mysql, subquery

I've 3 tables (contents, tags, contents_tags).

It's available at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b0338

I need one query that return something like this:

```
+------------+--------+----------------+
| contents.id| title  | tag            |
+------------+--------+----------------+
|     1      | News 1 | News, Articles |
|     2      | News 2 | News           |
+------------+--------+----------------+
```

Comment: `JOIN` + `GROUP_CONCAT()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use join and group_concat

Try this

```
select id, title, tag from contents 
join 
 (select id_content, GROUP_CONCAT(tag) as tag from contents_tags 
  join tags on contents_tags.id_tag=tags.id group by id_content) t on
contents.id=t.id_content
```